# Prevent Delete with Inheriting Permissions

Tags: sharepoint

I am looking to create a custom permission level for my list, but dont want to have to choose all the users.  Is this possible?  There are thousands of users on my site already with contribute permissions, and I want all of them to have access to my list, but not able to delete items.  The problem is, I dont want to individually set the permission level for each member (as I cannot possibly pick out who all may use my list).

Thank you!

Comment: are they all available in a sharepoint group?

Comment: No, they are in hundreds of groups for multiple lists across the site.

Comment: do you want this to be set to all the users of the site?

Answer (score 0):

Add a group and give it Read permissions. And add all users to the group. And give an access to the list  for the group/

Comment: I cannot add all users, because I could not possibly imagine who all might use my list.  This is for a large corporation with thousands of users.